# How would it be possible to use variadic function without passing number of arguments and only with 3 dots?

Tags: c++, variadic

Considering the code below, is it possible to define a variadic function without getting number of arguments?

```
void printFunction(...)
{
    int noOfArgs = "Any way to get number of arguments?";
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, noOfArgs);
    cout << va_arg(args, int) << endl;
    for (int i = 2; i <= noOfArgs; i++)
    {
        cout << va_arg(args, int) << endl;
    }
    va_end(args);
}


int main()
{

    printFunction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use parameter packs for that now.

Comment: You should not use "ellipsis" function in C++ anymore at all

Comment: Btw how you plan to use such function without knowing what type of parameters were passed? (lets say you realize how many were passed)

Comment: @Slava *" You should not use "ellipsis" function in C++ anymore at all "* May I ask why?

Comment: @MehdiCharife because before there were no way around, but now C++ has mechanism to handle them with type safe code.

Answer (score 3):

Getting the amount of arguments is not possible in C `va_args`. The best you can do is to use a magic value that ends the sequence and a macro to hide it from your user:

```
#define printFunction(...) actualPrintFunction(__VA_ARGS__, 42)
void actualPrintFunction(int first, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, first);
    int arg;
    std::cout << first << endl;
    while((arg = va_arg(args, int)) != 42)
    {
        cout << arg << endl;
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, you could alternatively use C++ fold expressions. The above has the advantage of being compatible with C and compiling faster, while the C++ approach gives you **type safety**.

Comment: Your answer does not make much sense (as the question does not), how such function would be used? How it would know what type of parameters were passed?

Comment: This would really only work if all arguments were of the same fixed data type (`int` in the question) and (as I wrote) even then, there's no way to really be sure. Apart from passing number sequences, I can't really think of a practical usecase either.

Comment: If all arguments are of the same type then there is no reason at all to use ellipsis, pass `int **` for C or `std::vecto<int>` for C++.

Comment: @user3684240 Not necessarily quite as limited. Only the type of first variadic argument has to be fixed. The other types can depend on the value of the previous arguments (or, the value of the named argument could be used, as is done with `printf`). Whether that is useful is another matter though.

Comment: @eerorika Good point, though in practice that sounds too scary to me to actually ever do in production code.

Comment: @eerorika if other types are depend on the previous then first type must be fixed, so we come back to original - there must be at least one parameter before ellipsis.

Comment: *"The above has the advantage of being compatible with C"* Well, it's not compatible because it contains `cout`. And in any case, it's very rare that code intercompatibility between C and C++ is relevant has any value. They are such different languages that there is basically no practical code sharing anymore between them.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with intercompatibility being irrelevant and of no practical value, but yeah, you're obviously right about the rest. `cout` could be quite easily replaced here, though, which I thought was fairly obvious.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The *interface* is compatible with C. And there are a lot of programs that call functions across languages, and in particular between C and C++.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ 11 and after, it is very easy:

```
template<typename... Arguments>
void printFunction(Arguments &&...args) {
    auto noOfArgs = sizeof...(Arguments);
```

However, you are using an old-style, plain-C, preprocessor macro style, which is very different.
First, to use the preprocessor macros you need to have at least one named parameter, which will be used to start the `va_list`, and that's the beginning of the complications.

I think there is no standard way to count the number of arguments, it can be implemented in a number of ways, if that is what you are really asking, which I would have tagged as `C` instead of `C++`.

How to access the arguments: there are two choices, let us call it the "machine gun" and the "drip-drip-drip" --these are my names--:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename... Ts>
void ignoreResults(Ts &&...) {}

template<typename Argument>
int machineGunBullet(Argument &&arg);

inline void drip() {} // do nothing

template<typename A1, typename... Tail>
void drip(A1 &&a1, Tail &&...tail) {
    // do something here with a1
    drip(std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
}

template<typename... Arguments>
void printFunction(Arguments &&...args) {
    ignoreResults(machineGunBullet(std::forward<Arguments>(args))...);
    // or
    drip(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
}
```

This builds in the compiler explorer,
https://godbolt.org/z/aSx2wv

Answer (score 1):

There is technically one way, which is analogous to how it is possible to get the length of a null terminated string: Use particular argument value to designate the end of the argument list.

However, note that in order to use `va_start`, there must be at least one named parameter. In your example you attempt to pass a local variable into `va_start` which is not allowed. That macro doesn't take "the number of arguments". It takes "last named argument  before variadic parameters start".

That said: I recommend against using C-style variadic functions.